# Comma before "and" in "that" clause?

Tags: commas

Which one is a better usage of a comma? (Grammarly says the latter one is right)

> I also remember that he justified the Spearman rank correlation and rigorously proved a large sample normal approximation of it.

or

> I also remember that he justified the Spearman rank correlation, and rigorously proved a large sample normal approximation of it.

The only difference is that "," is added before the "and." or not.

Here I intended to say that "he" justified and also proved.

Comment: The comma is **not incorrect** and helps readability. It is compatible with most writing styles.

Comment: This may have little to do with the "that" clause.

Comment: The comma aids readability, especially for those with smaller lung capacity. There is no added ambiguity; I remember X and did Y' is infelicitous.

Answer (score 1):

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (16th edition: 6.29, page 317) would disagree with *Grammarly*. In the section *Commas with compound predicates* it states:

> A comma is not normally used between the parts of a compound predicate—that is, two or more verbs having the same subject... .
>
> - He printed out a week's worth of crossword puzzles and arranged them on his clipboard.

It says also:

> A comma may occasionally be needed, however, to prevent a misreading...
>
> - She recognised the man who entered the room, and gasped.

In other words, *she recognised... and she gasped*. On this basis it seems to me that including the comma actually makes the sentence potentially ambiguous. It could be interpreted as:

- I also remember that... and I rigorously proved...

Comment: Whoa! Perfect logic applied incorrectly, I'm afraid. [I also remember ...] [**he** justified ...] and [(**he**) rigorously proved ...]